# Firewall rules and external TCP Load Balancers in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, load-balancing, firewall

I have an unmanaged instance group that has 2 VM Instances in it with an external IP Address of, let's say `1.2.3.4` and `1.2.3.5`. After that, I created an **External TCP LoadBalancer** for this instance group (as the backend service). After creating this load balancer, I received the frontend IP Address of that loadBalancer (which I assume is the IP Address of the forwarding rule) and let's say this IP Address is `5.6.7.8`. Now, when we create a loadbalancer we need to create health checks and create a firewall rule to allow that health check to communicate with each VMs.. Hence, I created a firewall rule, ingress, allow, to port 80 (by the way everything here is port 80... that's the only port I use) with Source IPV4 ranges are `209.85.204.0/22` `209.85.152.0/22` `35.191.0.0/16` (port 80) where these IPv4  ranges are available in Google's Documentation page.

Now, the load balancer declares that the backend service are healthy. So then, I wanted to make a firewall rule for my VMs (instance group) that only allow ingress from the frontend IP of the load balancer, that is ingress, allow, source IPv4 ranges `5.6.7.8/32` (again port 80) to my VMs,, thinking that it will work. However, when I input the IP address in my browser, it does not "redirect" to the respective VMs (that is `1.2.3.4` and `1.2.3.5`). It only works if i put `0.0.0.0/0` as the source IPv4. Hence, it is kinda useless for having two firewalls (one for healthchecks one for forwarding rule).

The reason I want to do this is because I only want my VMs to receive incoming ingress from the load balancer frontend IP address, such then if i put `1.2.3.4` or `1.2.3.5` in my browser it will not connect. It connects if and only if I put `5.6.7.8`.

Is this achievable?

Thank you in advance!!

Edit: All resources are in the same region and zone!

Comment: Hover over some of your tags and find out why your question is off topic here. Then read this: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#health-checks), the firewall rule must allow the following source ranges:

- 130.211.0.0/22
- 35.191.0.0/16

Also, you can read this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#how-connections-work). The IP `5.6.7.8` is not the source IP that sends to your backend from LB. LB sent to your backend is from the same range used by health check:
`35.191.0.0/16` `130.211.0.0/22.`

Suggestion:

You might use tcpdump to see what IP sends to your VM.

---

Tag the backend instances "application," and create a firewall rule with the target tag "application" and the source IP range of the allowed clients and Google health check IP ranges.